# How to add a number to each element in list a that gives a new list b with sum added number

Tags: python, list

Hi How to add a number to each integer in the list A that generates new list B using python. also I want to generate n number of lists
Example:
a = [1,2,3] and n = 2
add k = 3 to each element in a that gives b = [4,5,6] and add k to list b that gives c = [7,8,9]
I achieved this using map function but I want to generate n number of lists.

```py
def bw(n, k):
    test_list = [1,2,3]
    if n > 1:
        res = list(map(lambda x :x+k, test_list))
        return test_list, res
    else:
        return test_list
print bw(3, 2)
```

Output b = [4,5,6]
       c = [7,8,9]

Comment: Why `map` and `lambda` rather than the more readable `res = [x+k for x in test_list]` ? Also, if you want to do it `n` times, why not just use a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the final array:

```
def bw(n, k):
    test_list = [1,2,3]
    return [x+n*k for x in test_list]

print(bw(3, 2))
```

If you want a list of lists as well:

```
def bw(n, k):
    test_list = [1,2,3]
    res = []
    for i in range(0,n):
        test_list = [x+k for x in test_list]
        res.append(test_list)

    return test_list, res

print(bw(3, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res = [x + k for x in test_list]
```

This is straight from [GeeksforGeeks.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-adding-k-to-each-element-in-a-list-of-integers/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```py
test_list = [1,2,3]

def bw(test_list, n, k):
    output= []
    temp = test_list
    for i in range(n):
        temp = [j + k for j in temp]
        output.append(temp)
    return output

print (bw(test_list, 2, 3))
```